# Google maps API javascript

Tags: javascript, php, api, google-maps

HI I'm having problem with google maps API on my page http://topdoctor.eu.pn/
where a name associated with doctors includes link to their address. 
As I'm creating API key in code.google.com under API access and creating the key under Simple API Access where the key is generated. 
Then I have the scipt on my site

```
var map;

var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'map': map,draggable: true }); 
var mapprint;

    function initialize()
    {
        var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(00,00);
    var marker;
    var mapProp = {
      center:myCenter,
      zoom:14,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
     map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
      marker=new google.maps.Marker({
      position:myCenter,
      icon:"Your image path on map",
      });
    marker.setMap(map);
          var info ="Your Info";


         var myOptions = {
                 content: info
                ,disableAutoPan: false
                ,maxWidth: 0
                ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(20, -158) //used for positioning left,right
                ,zIndex: null
                ,boxStyle: { 
                  background: ""
                  ,opacity: 1.0
                  ,width: "220px"
                 }
                ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
                ,closeBoxURL: ""
                ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
                ,isHidden: false
                ,pane: "floatPane"
                ,enableEventPropagation: false
                ,url:"http://www.topdoctor.eu.pn/"
            };
         var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                ib.open(map, this);
            });

             google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (e) {
                ib.closeListener_ = google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'click', ib.getCloseClickHandler_());
                ib.close();

            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(ib, "click", function (e) {

                window.parent.location.href = "http://www.topdoctor.eu.pn/";
            });

            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
     <style type="text/css">
     body{background-color:#fff;}
     </style>

    <div id="googleMap" class="gmap" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>



    <div id="map-canvas">



    </div><!-- map -->
```

but the map doesn't show or it says the key isn't enabled or the quota has been reached even if no or very little traffic is on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure status of Google Maps JavaScript API is `ON` and as Written over there `Courtesy limit: 25,000 requests/day` means you can request 25,000 in a day.
For checking the whole request details Click on `Report` menu and check the details of traffic for your API.If it Cross the Limit than you will not able to use API for that particular day.

All you can find [here](https://code.google.com/apis/console)

Comment: The API is enabled and I'm getting these stats. 
Traffic Reports for TopDoctor
Total requests
15
Requests/day
3 peak 0.54 average
 
Start Date
Jun 14, 2014
 
Sample Period
28 days 

so there is no way the limit has been reached but the map doesn't display under the profile

Comment: Cross check your data usage using the the link on right hand side `Download Historical Quota Usage Data`

Comment: that shows this     
Maps API v3
# of requests
  
Daily quota: 25k
  
28-day total: 15